# Warning: Return code of 127 for check of service was out of bounds. Make sure the plugin you're trying to run actually exists

Tags: nagios

I'm trying to use the phanton-js plugin for Nagios:
https://github.com/hggh/phantomjs-nagios

but despite me double checking the set-up, I'm getting 
"Return code 127 is out of bounds : Plugin may be missing"

The plugin file exists in the plugins folder:

```
# stat /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_http_load_time.rb
  File: `/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_http_load_time.rb'
  Size: 9108            Blocks: 24         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fc01h/64513d    Inode: 275201      Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
```

I can execute it when su'd to the nagios user locally:

```
-bash-4.1$ whoami
nagios
-bash-4.1$ /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/phantomjs-nagios/check_http_load_time.rb -u https://google.com -w 2 -c 3
OK: https://google.com load time: 0.43
```

This is how it is defined in the checkcommands.cfg file:

```
define command {
        command_name    check_web_page_load_time
        command_line    $USER1$/check_http_load_time.rb -u $ARG1$ -w $ARG2$ -c $ARG3$
        }
```

and this is the service definition

```
define service {
  use                   generic-service
  host_name             test_host
  service_description   https://google.com web load time
  check_command         check_web_page_load_time!https://google.com!2!3
  contact_groups        support-emails
}
```

I've restarted nagios and confirmed that the config check passes.

Am I missing something obvious?

edit:

plugin file is located in 2 folders:

```
/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_http_load_time.rb
```

and

```
/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/phantomjs-nagios/check_http_load_time.rb
```

both files are identical, both can be executed by the nagios user successfully and neither location works with command definition. I tried calling it with full path and with the $USR1$ variable, which points to the standard location where all the other plugins are located

```
/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/
```

Comment: Look at your nagios.log file and search for clue.

Comment: Already tried it, it does not add any more information, even in debug mode:

    
    Warning: Return code of 127 for check of service 'https://www.google.com web load time' on host 'test_host' was out of bounds. Make sure the plugin you're trying to run actually exists.

Answer (score 1):

Manged to eventually solve it. The error message was not very helpful, as problem was with the environment variables of the nagios user.
The original script had the following shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

After changing it to the actual location of ruby binary the script works:

```
#!/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby
```

Still surprised that it worked when su'd to the Nagios user.

Comment: I suggest you to read this article - https://www.tecmint.com/difference-between-su-and-su-commands-in-linux/ about difference between `su -` and `su`.